# Are azure app service backups available post march 31st?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

In regards to this statement from microsoft for azure app services taken from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-disaster-recovery

"Starting March 31, 2025, Azure App Service web applications will no longer be placed in disaster recovery mode during a disaster in an Azure region as explained in the recover from region-wide failure article. We encourage you to implement commonly used disaster recovery techniques to prevent loss of functionality or data for your web apps if there's a regional disaster"

Does this mean the backups won't be available via the portal if there was an outage after this point?

[image]

Comment: Based on my understanding yes, region-wide disaster app services will no longer be marked as recoverable, Azure recommends implementing [multi-region][1] resource deployment with Azure front door, but these recommendations increase the resource costs, one of the best workarounds is to achieve automation excellence like if you can deploy your apps in another region in less than 10 min you can stop being worried about disaster!


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/reliability-app-service?tabs=graph%2Ccli#active-active-architecture

Comment: Ideally, Automatic backups are not managed by customer if the region is down then you on't able to restore it.  Also, automatic backup is resilient to zone down failure not to region failures. Custom backups are stored in the storage account that will be managed by customer if the Storage account has Cross region read replica (ex: RAGZRS) for it to be accessible when region is down.

Answer (score 0):

> Beginning 31 March 2025, we'll no longer place Azure App Service web applications in disaster recovery mode in the event of a disaster in an Azure region. We strongly encourage you to implement commonly used disaster recovery techniques to prevent loss of functionality or data for your web apps if there's a regional disaster.

> - None.  [Restoring an automatic backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup#restore-a-backup)  usually requires  **Standard**  or  **Premium**  tier, but in disaster recovery mode, it's automatically enabled for your impacted app, regardless which tier the impacted app is in.

As disaster recovery mode will be disabled from 31st March 2025, The Automatic backup will not be enabled for the impacted app, You need to implement Custom scheduled backup for your web apps. But until 31st March 2025 you can use automatic backups.

This also means Azure won't place your Azure App service web app automatically in the disaster recovery mode. You need to implement a disaster recovery strategy whether multi-region or zone redundant by yourself. Refer this [**MS Q & A question**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1195123/beginning-31-march-2025-app-service-web-apps-will) on the same warning.

Also, The easiest way to perform disaster recovery is to Create 2 CI/CD pipelines where one is your Active pipeline that deploys and manages your Production workload. If Production workload is down due to any disaster, You can run the duplicate 2nd pipeline for the deployment and management of your App. Or move your existing app to another region before.

Refer this **[table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/reliability/reliability-app-service?tabs=graph,cli#back-up--restore-vs-disaster-recovery)** for more details. In this table it is recommended to configure custom backup for your Web app and also configure Multi-region Disaster recovery manually by using Active-Active, Active-Passive, Passive-Cold region techniques as mentioned in the same Document as the table.

***For App Service Web Apps

(Basic\Standard\Premium Pricing Tier)***

> In Azure App Service, You can make on-demand custom backups or utilize automatic backups. You can restore a backup by overwriting an existing app by restoring to a new app or slot.      Refer to [Back up and restore your app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup) for more info.

***For App Service Environment (V2 & V3)***

> In Azure App Service Environment, You can make on-demand custom backups or utilize automatic backups. Automatic
> backups can be restored to a target app within the same ASE, not in another ASE. Custom backups can be restored to a target app in another ASE (such as from a V2 ASE to a V3 ASE). Backups can be restored to target app of the same OS platform as the source app.

***App Service Web Apps  (Free & Shared Pricing Tier)***

> If you have web applications deployed to the Free or Shared tier and require access to Back up and Restore capabilities for these web apps, scale up to Basic tier or higher.

***Restore Automatic backup:-***

*Every 1 hour:-*

[image]

*I have restored the automatic Backup in the new app.*

***Custom Backup:-***

*I scheduled one Custom backup manually:-*

[image]

*Restore Custom backup:-*

[image]

*You can restore Custom backup in new app.*